# Listen live calls on Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-sdk

I'm trying to create an interactive dashboard that shows Twilio calls with the ability to listen to any ongoing calls. Is it possible? And what is the best approach I should take?

I saw two methods on the documentation which are [Twiml Voice:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream)  and [Twiml Voice:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference) . Conference doesn't suit with my scenario because incoming calls are not ringing. And I couldn't find a way to listen to voice Streams on the documentation.

Note: Currently inbound calls are handled by Twilio function and WebSocket and outbound calls are handled by Twilio JavaScript SDK.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain why the `<Stream>` tag won't suit you? I don't get what you mean with "incoming calls are not ringing". I'd suggest to make use of this tag in the Twilio function.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `<Conference>` doesn't suit me. When an incoming call initiated it connects without ringing.

Comment: Have you tried `<Stream>`? What issues did you have with this approach? There's a great blog post from my colleague in which he's explaining how to use it https://www.twilio.com/blog/live-transcribing-phone-calls-using-twilio-media-streams-and-google-speech-text

Comment: That's a great blog post. Thanks for that. I still couldn't figure out how to playback that stream from client side?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen to a live Voicecall you could try the Stream as IObert suggests. Or, you must use the Conference feature and add yourself as a "Coach." Don't be put off by the name Conference. Think of it as a Voicecall with many more helpful features. You can create a conference from an outbound call like this:

```
string accountSid = "ACxxxxxx";
string authToken = "xxxxx";

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var voiceresponse = new VoiceResponse();

var say = new Say("Setting up your conference.");

var dialConference = new Dial();
dialConference.Conference(
        name: "Your Conference"
        startConferenceOnEnter: true,
        endConferenceOnExit: true       
    );

voiceresponse.Append(say);
voiceresponse.Append(dialConference);

var twiml = voiceresponse.ToString();

var call = CallResource.Create(
            twiml: new Twilio.Types.Twiml(twiml),
            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("E164 Number to Dial"),
            from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("E164 Your Twilio Number")           
        );
```

Then once you have a conference started, you can add the second call from either an inbound or outbound call. With an inbound call, use Twiml to send the call to the conference. With an outbound call, use the REST API to add a Conference Participant.

From the client side, using the Twilio Javascript Client, you would then connect your device to the Conference with the correct Conference Twiml parameters which is explained here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#deviceconnectconnectoptions

```
const device = new Device(token);

let call = await device.connect({ 
  params: {
    To: 'Your Conference'
  } 
});
```

I use a slightly different method...I use a button on the client that when you click it makes an outbound call to the "coach" using the Conference Participant REST API. The coach answers and is added with mute = true. The "coach" uses the Twilio Client for WebRTC but the same process will work with a "regular" phone line with a phone number. Using the Twilio Client in this way allows the coach to listen on their computer speakers which is convenient.

The harder part is you will need to keep track of which calls are active on the client side. Otherwise, you won't have an accurate list of which calls or conferences are active. Repeatedly polling the Twilio REST API for active calls is not recommended by Twilio and is super slow compared to using the webhooks to notify of call status changes.

Comment: I created the conference from a Twilio function and when I call to the twilio number I hear a music, that means conference has created, right?  But I couldn't connect to the conference using the sdk (I used your code). It says "Application error has occurred" Also get this on console `Received an error from the gateway: ConnectionError: ConnectionError (31005): Error sent from gateway in HANGUP`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, when you hear music that means you have successfully "initiated" a conference. The conference will actually begin (the music will stop) once the first participant joins. I am not sure what that error means and am not super familiar with the javascript client. Check for the [definition of that error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/error-codes). You are closer now that the conference has started.